# Difference between column assignment done using df.loc[] vs df[index] in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My requirement is to replace the values of a column, i wanted to understand the difference between doing it by Approach #1 vs Approach #2

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10000000).reshape(1000000, 10))
```

Approach #1

```
%time df[8] = np.arange(1000000)
```

Approach #2

```
%time df.loc[:, 8] = np.arange(1000000)
```

What is the recommended approach and why ?

Comment: There is no functional difference. Any performance difference is system-specific and an **implementation detail**, you shouldn't rely on it. Complexity is the same.

Comment: Can anybody explain why the question has been down voted ? I don't see anything wrong with the question, in fact i haven't got any convincing answer from pandas community.

Answer (score 0):

`df.loc[:, 8]` will go slower than direct indexing `df[8]`
due to a cost of `pandas.DataFrame.loc` invocation which is this case `:` accepts *"A slice object"*.